# Macro getting confused differentiating ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

1st post, but not 1st time visitor - this forum has been an invaluable help in developping my VBA coding skills over the last 3 years - so a big thank you.

Here's a weird issue I've encountered.

I've created a month end template for my team to use. 
This template stores a number of Macros, including some activated by keyboard short cuts. Those short cuts activated macros are all run on other reports in CSV format.

I've ensured that the macro would stop running if the active workbook was the main workbook, as it does a lot of formatting and would seriously damage the main workbook.

So this fail safe short code will be run hundreds of time a day..... and occasionally, once or twice a month, excel gets confused. Even though the ActiveWorkbook isn't ThisWorkbook, it acts like it is and aborts the macro.

'Prevents from running the macro on the Month End Allocation Template

```
Dim w As Workbook

Set w = ActiveWorkbook

If w Is ThisWorkbook Then
Exit Sub

End If
```

I can't really get my head around it, the code is pretty simple, and has 100% prevented unwanted damages to the main workbook (the main thing really), but occasionally prevents the formatting macro to be run other workbooks.

In those rare instances it happens, the user has to close all excel workbooks, and once reopened, it will work again just fine.  :|

Is it just an excel bug? Is there something here I didn't consider and should this code be improved? I love its simplicity, and it has 100% avoided damages to the main workbook, I'm just annoyed that excel seemingly gets confused by what ThisWorkbook is/should be, and that i cannot explain it.

Comment: Why don't you define the other workbooks? `Set w = Workbooks.Open(Path & name)` or `Set w = Workbooks(Name & extension)` the use of the `ActiveWorkbook`should be avoided as much as possible.

Comment: The same way you want to avoid relying on the `.Selected` cell or range, you will want to avoid relying on the `.Active` workbook &/or worksheet. Relying on these methods leaves room for user error which is no good. There is no need to do this when you can **explicitly** state what your two books are as noted by @Damian

Comment: @Damian this would be challenging. The workbook name is variable and comprise the month year (format MMYYYY), which would be easy, but also a store number which could be any of 830 stores numbered between 1 and 2000. The store number would be a big stumbling block. I'll look into it, but since the user manually opens the workbook on which they will run the macro, I'm not sure I'll be able to define the store number. I'm might be able to go around itwith comparing just part of the workbook's name though, as this is predictable.

Comment: @urdearboy, I thought ThisWorkbook was pretty solid? The reference to the active workbook has worked very well to avoid the macro being run on ThisWorkbook, but for some reason I can't understand, the Active Workbook is confused with Thisworkbook. It will happen once or twice a month, and i can see it - in debug mode, starting from the target workbook (what should be the active workbook), the VBA codes ends up exiting the sub thinking it is ThisWorkbook. If the user closes all excel windows and starts again, it then works fine.

Comment: @urdearboy you are correct though, and i've been pretty specific with most of my coding lately.

Comment: You could always use the workbook names in the assignment, like the suggestion to use the path.  you get that as a variable and use it in the assignment, you don't have to actually know the workbook name in advance (compile time).

Comment: I Usually specify workbook/sheet/range/action is it is also simpler to keep track of what is happening where, which is an added benefit. In this case though, it seems like excel simply bugs? I will see if I can redefine the target workbook name as yourself and @ Damian suggested, however I can't specify it fully, which is annoying and why preventing the macro from running on ThisWorkbook only is an attractive option.

Comment: How have you proved that the workbook running the code isn't active? (The process of debugging could make the code book active.) Is it possible that the user has clicked on the workbook while the code is running?

Comment: @HackSlash, whenever that has happened I run the debugger for them. Selecting the target (active workbook), and running through the macro pressing F8.

Comment: @HackSlash so I know it should work, and should prevent doing anything on the main workbook. It's strange it works 99.9% of the time, and then nope. Excel seems to throw a fit, and it believes the target / active workbook is ThisWorkbook. Weird. Close it all down, reopen start again and it works. Unless it's a bug, it has me puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

Any main workbook that you don't want users to mess up should have protections that are turned off and on by your macros. Separate your data from your views. Lock the views and modify only the data. For you this means the CSV would import in to columns on a hidden sheet and then the data on your protected sheet with the linked data table would just magically update. There should be no formatting macro. The format is static. The linked data is what changes.

Comment: I try to do this when appropriate, but here the user need to open and review large number of reports.

Comment: I suppose I could try to format the main template to create buttons that would enable the user the open the stores report and run the macro then(the reports formats are pretty dire, hence the need to reformat in something that can be easily interpreted). Food for thoughts for sure. I assumed preventing the macro from executing in ThisWorkbook was safe? (Since those code have never executed on the main workbook, I've at least achieved that, if perhaps not in the best practice manner...... lol )